# OAuth2.0 Flow for background services or daemons

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2

I am currently developing a background service that will use the Salesforce APIs to interact with the underlying data (e.g. pull/update).

This service isn't acting on behalf of any particular user and I am a little confused on the best OAuth2.0 Authentication Flow to use for this use case?

For the moment I have used the Username/Password flow with a dummy user I have setup with the correct permission levels.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into the JWT bearer token flow? this flow is good for server to server background processes:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: Another vote here for using the JWT Bearer flow. OP, you'll still need to use  another flow to do the initial authorization, but after that the JWT flow is completely headless.

Comment: Can you use the JWT bearer token flow without using a certificate?

Comment: @DerekF I didn't realize that the JWT flow still required an initial authorization flow.  I thought the whole purpose of JWT was to avoid the interactive login required by most of the other flows (web server, user agent, etc).   If you still need to perform an interactive login before using JWT, how can that be done for a headless background service like the OP's?

Comment: @DavidCheng Yep, it's mentioned in the help docs that you need to authorize with a flow that produces a refresh token first. The upside is that you aren't required to go through an interactive flow (again, the flow needing to generate a refresh token seems to be a requirement) on a headless machine. You can do it through some other machine. The important bit is that the Connected App has been used in an interactive flow before using the JWT flow.

Comment: @DerekF aha!  That is not intuitive and not well-explained in the doc.  So as long as I use the same username, I can do the interactive flow from some other machine, that is good to know.

Comment: Hi both, just to confirm 2 things. 1) JWT must be used with a generated certificate? 2) you are specifying a username to use, are you restricted based on the permissions of this user?